# label priting via button

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i am trying to print out the day of the week when a number is typed into the text box but it doesn't seem to print on the label at all once i click the button, when i run the code it seems to work fine up until when i enter a value and click the button, nothing happens.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int dayOfWeek = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1);
            String dayName = null;
            switch (dayOfWeek)
            {
                case 1:
                    dayName = "Sunday";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    dayName = "Monday";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    dayName = "Tuesday";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    dayName = "Wednesday";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    dayName = "Thursday";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    dayName = "Friday";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    dayName = "Saturday";
                    break;



                    String stndrd = null;
                    if (dayOfWeek == 1)
                    {
                        stndrd = dayName;
                        label1.Text = (stndrd);
                    }
                    else if (dayOfWeek == 2)
                    {
                        stndrd = dayName;
                        label1.Text = (stndrd);
                    }
                    else if (dayOfWeek == 3)
                    {
                        stndrd = dayName;
                        label1.Text = (stndrd);
                    }
                    else if (dayOfWeek == 4)
                    {
                        stndrd = dayName;
                        label1.Text = (stndrd);
                    }
                    else if (dayOfWeek == 5)
                    {
                        stndrd = dayName;
                        label1.Text = (stndrd);
                    }
                    else if (dayOfWeek == 6)
                    {
                        stndrd = dayName;
                        label1.Text = (stndrd);
                    }
                    else if (dayOfWeek == 7)
                    {
                        stndrd = dayName;
                        label1.Text = (stndrd);
                    }
                    else if (dayOfWeek == null)
                    {
                        stndrd = "Mad Day!!!";
                        label1.Text = (stndrd);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @C.Evenhuis's answer, your section of code that is setting the label is inside, but after the break, of the case statement of the 'case 7' switch. This code will be unreachable with your current code and hence why the label itself would not be set to anything since the code is never executed.

You will need to finish the switch statement and then perform the setting of the label.
But all that code is also redundant since you can do it all in a much simpler way (extending on C.Evenhuis's recommendation)

```
int dayOfWeek;
if (!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out dayOfWeek))
{
  // you can remove the MessageBox if you're not interested in feedback 
  MessageBox.Show("Value entered is not a valid day number!");
  return;
}

String dayName = null;
switch (dayOfWeek)
{
  case 1:
    dayName = "Sunday";
    break;
  case 2:
    dayName = "Monday";
    break;
  case 3:
    dayName = "Tuesday";
    break;
  case 4:
    dayName = "Wednesday";
    break;
  case 5:
    dayName = "Thursday";
    break;
  case 6:
    dayName = "Friday";
    break;
  case 7:
    dayName = "Saturday";
    break;
  default:
    dayName = "Mad Day!!!";
    break;
  }
  // Set the label's text to what was defined above
  label1.Text = dayName;
}
```

Comment: hi, i have just tried this and when i click on the button i still get no change of data on the label

Comment: That is strange because I have the exact code on my side in the `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` event method (only that code and nothing else). Are you sure that the button's OnClick event is set and that the TextBox and Labels are visible and correctly referenced?

Comment: ahh i just realized that the TextBox was not referenced properly, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
int dayOfWeek = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1);
```

Attempts to convert the *TextBox* to an integer, not the value typed inside it (`textBox1.Text`). You should change it to something like:

```
int dayOfWeek;
if (!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out dayOfWeek))
{
    // you can remove the MessageBox if you're not interested in feedback 
    MessageBox.Show("Value entered is not a valid day number!");
    return;
}

String dayName = null;
switch (dayOfWeek)
{
    //...
```

By using `int.TryParse()` you prevent exceptions and are able to handle "illegal values".